# How to turn off generators for RSpec 2 in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, code-generation, rails-generate

I installed the current RSpec 2 Beta under Rails 3 RC as mentioned on the GitHub page (and several blogs). Everything works fine, but I am not able to turn off specific generators like advised on some blogs.

Here is what I do in ./config/application.rb:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec, :fixtures => false, :views => false
end
```

But when doing a "rails g scaffold Model name:string" those view specs are still generated.
What's wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to pass the `:view_specs => false` option too. I don't know why this is different between the controller generator (where `:views => false` has effect) and scaffold. I'll ask David.

Comment: Thanks for taking care of this. "view_specs => false" works. Is that somewhere documented? With trial and error I also found out that there is a "routing_specs => false". But there is no "model_specs => false" ... I didn't figure that out.

Comment: @Zardos: no problem! I just looked in the code for the generator. Whilst it's helpful if you know where to look it would be *really* helpful if this was documented.

Comment: @RyanBigg thanks for the :view_specs tip, I ran into same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can not stop generation of model spec, that is necessary and if you hope into the source code for rspec generator model/model_generator.rb you'll find there is no class_option :model_spec ....

Options allowd are give below, except webrat that can also be added or

```
config.generators do |g| 
  g.test_framework :rspec, :view_specs => false, :controller_specs => false, 
    :helper_specs => false, :routing_specs => false, :fixture => true,
    :fixture_replacement => "factory_girl"
end
```